# boost::make_shared and C++Builder VCL objects

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, vcl, make-shared

I've tried switching some C++Builder 2010 code using `new` to use `boost::make_shared<>`, as below.

Old:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TStringList> l(new TStringList());
```

New:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TStringList> l(boost::make_shared<TStringList>());

l->Add("foo"); //dies here
```

The old code works, but the new code dies when I try and use the pointer (AV, or just hangs).
I've used `make_shared` and `shared_ptr` successfully before, but never with `TObject` descendants. Is this a known problem - perhaps something to do withe the way `make_shared` uses placement `new()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the `placement new` is indeed problematic because `TObject` has expectations about memory allocations which `new` satisfies (because C++Builder's RTL internally routes C/C++ memory routines to Delphi RTL routines in VCL projects), but which `placement new` does not.

Comment: Odd how things come back to bite you. Three years on, I trip over the exact same problem, and google - and StackOverflow - lead me to a question I'd forgotten I even asked ;)